# Get in which range of dates is a date in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, date, range

I have got an array with one or more arrays:

For example, with one array:

```
var array1 = [['2','name','surname','2014-01-01']];
```

Or with more than one(It is dynamic, sometimes it comes with 1 other with 2, with 3,... but always with the date ordered 'asc').

```
var array1 = [['2','name','surname','2014-01-01'],['2','name1','surname1','2014-02-02'],['2','name2','surname2','2014-03-03'],['2','name3','surname3','2014-04-02']];
```

Then I have got a date:

```
var givenDate="2014-03-28";
```

I want to get the array where givenDate is in the range. I want the beginning array. In this case the 3rd array:`['2','name2','surname2','2014-03-03']`

I dont know which is the most effective way.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

EDIT:
This will either return an array with an exact match of the givendate. If no exact match is found it will return the array with the date closest to the givendate:

```
var array1 = [['2','name','surname','2014-01-01'],['2','name1','surname1','2014-02-02'],['2','name2','surname2','2014-03-03'],['2','name3','surname3','2014-04-02']];
var givenDate = '2014-02-12';
var key = false;
var index;
var differences = [];
for( index=0; index < array1.length; ++index ){
    if( array1[index][3] == givenDate ){
        key = index;
    }       
}
if( !key ){
    for( index=0; index < array1.length; ++index ){
        difference = givenDate.replace(/-/g, '') - array1[index][3].replace(/-/g, '')
        differences[difference] = [];
        differences[difference]['key'] = index;
    }   
}
if( key ){
    alert( 'Exact match for given date is found and holds key: ' + key );
    alert( 'Resulting array: ' + array1[key] );         
}
if( differences.length > 0 ){
    alert( 'Found a nearest key' );
    var firstKey = getFirstKey(differences);
    alert( 'Resulting Array: ' + array1[differences[firstKey]['key']] );
}
function getFirstKey( data ) {
    for (elem in data ) 
        return elem;
}
```

Comment: I think OP wanted the date that is in the "range" not exact matches.

Comment: As of his question: Then I have got a date:

var givenDate="2014-03-28"; 

He did not specify a range, but a single date. How can he match inside a range with a single date?

Comment: OP: "I want to get the array where givenDate is in the *range*. I want the beginning array. In this case the 3rd array:`['2','name2','surname2','2014-03-03']`"

Comment: Thats still not a range. That is he wants the keys of the array where dates are less than the givendate

Comment: And if the given date is: `var givenDate="2014-03-28";`

Comment: Well then I updated my response to cover either scenario. Now making it possible to get multiple responses of array positions containing date either equal or less to givendate

Comment: yea, my bad. Didnt have time to test the code before I posted it. It is now corrected

Comment: It is giving me a lot of results:
I only want one:
http://jsfiddle.net/dak8xvv5/6/

Comment: So you want the one that matches your date exactly? Not in a range?

Comment: See my last edit now Za7Pi. That will only return the one array element containing the exact match of specified date

Comment: I have put a different date and it is not working: 
http://jsfiddle.net/dak8xvv5/15/

Comment: The date you have put in that jsfiddle doesnt exist in any of the arrays. If you test this you will see it finds the third array where the date is: http://jsfiddle.net/dak8xvv5/19/

Comment: I know. I want to be in the range:
"I want to get the array where givenDate is in the range. I want the beginning array. In this case the 3rd array:`['2','name2','surname2','2014-03-03']`"

Comment: Exactly what do you mean with "in the range". Do you mean closest to the date specified in "givenDate" ?

Comment: Ok, an easier example: I have got this array: `var array1=[[2],[7],[17],[24],[33],[55]];`
and I have this number: `var givenNumber=19`; I need to know in what range is this number, and then get the first array. In this case, it is between `[17]` and `[24]`, and I need to take `[17]`. `[17]` is the first part of the range

Comment: Alright. I have submitted yet another edit. This is about as much work I can put into it, but you should be getting an idea now of how to do it from the example above.